# Php Exceptions Overwriting super class throw exception function

Tags: php

I am using a class which is suppose to connect to a bank payment gateway and execute the payment process.

However i am confused as that super class in the execution methord throws several exceptions.

```
     throw new Exception('Error: The CCV was incorrect for this card.',2);
```

**AND it stops there,**

however in my class function i need writes  to the DB as declined payment. Since i this function stops in the above code, my error reporting doesn't get executed..

my calling function looks like this

```
try{
    $dt = new ProcessCreditCardPayment($data);
        $dr = $dt->getReceipt();
        //print_r($dr);
    $response_code=$dr['txnResponseCode'];
    $this->successPayment($customer,$payment_ref,$response_code);
}
catch(Exception e){
    $response_code=$e->getCode();
    $this->declinedPayment($customer,$payment_ref,$response_code);  
}
```

any ideas ... ?

Comment: Is your code namespaced? Are you getting an error message, and if so, can you put it in your question?

Comment: not its not namespaced..  also its in the super class its throwing a exception ('this happned');